# Best flow rates of gas and liquid for a specific absorber

Tags: fluid-mechanics

I'm working on a university project about making an absorber function. It's made out of glass and it's very thin (about 6 in diameter). The packing is Berl Saddle made out of ceramic and it's about 0.5 inches. It has a bed height of about 1.406 meters.

My question is, how to determine the best liquid flow for a determined air flow? Since we won't be able to get a supply of NH3-Air mixture in time (nor the time to mix them ourselves),we only need to calculate the best flow rates for the absorber to not flood. We only need to calculate maximum liquid rate so the gas is enough.

I'm new to this, and my calculations were for reducing from X% NH3 to Y% NH3. Any help?

Comment: Nothing? I'm quite lost, any advice would be useful, I think.